# How to append a list in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation, how can I append a list? Tried:

```
!Join [ ",", [ !Ref ListParam, !Ref StringParam ]]
```

but got an error:

```
A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the
ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: every Fn::Join object
requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of
strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings
(such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, the second parameter can be:

- A list of strings, OR
- A function that returns a list of strings

You are providing a list that includes a Function *and* a String. That is most probably the problem.

You could try calling it first with `ListParam` to convert the list into a string, and then concatenate `String Param` to the end of it.

Meta-code:

- If `ListParam` = [a,b,c] and `StringParam` = 'd'
- Join(',', Join(',', ListParam), StringParam)

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to know what do you want to achieve.
If you want to append new a string parameter into a list and get the output in one String you can use `!Join`.
Because the characteristic of `!Join` is to appends a set of values into a single value.
If you want to do that you can try the code below:

```
!Join [ ",", [ !Join [ ",", [ !Ref ListParam ] ], !Ref StringParam ] ]
```

If you want to append those values into List type, you should try another way.
It will be easier if you provide the example case.