# How to create list of resource ARNS using a CommaDelimitedList parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a Cloudwatch event rule which will use multiple Codepipelines as source and triggers target.

```
Parameters:
  SourcePipeline:
    Description: Name of Source codepipeline
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: 'test3, test4'

Resources:
  PipelineTrigger:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.codepipeline
        resources: !Split 
          - ','
          - !Sub 
            - 'arn:aws:codepipeline:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${pipeline}'
            - pipeline: !Join 
                - ',arn:aws:codepipeline:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
                - !Ref SourcePipeline
```

Expecting `resources` as below:

```
  "resources": ["arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:123:test3","arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:123:test4"],
```

Any idea how to pass the list of names as a parameter?

@FYI Reference i am following [Using Lists of ARNs](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/03/17/cloudformation-tricks-part-1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be `!Ref SourcePipelines`. Second you forgot about comma. you can't do this the way you want. This is because, the first parameter to join must be literal string, not any CloudFormation expression or function. So you have to hardcode your account id and region:

```
        resources: !Split
          - ','
          - !Sub
            - 'arn:aws:codepipeline:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${pipeline}'
            - pipeline: !Join
                - ',arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:12312321:'
                - !Ref SourcePipelines
```

Comment: `Join` accepts `ListOfValues`  then we can from ARN with another`Join` and append `SourcePipelines` list to it right like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851161/how-to-append-a-list-in-cloudformation)

Comment: @SNR Thanks, Fixed that. But you still have missing comma and incorrect `SourcePipeline`. It should be `SourcePipelines`.

Comment: @SNR. And you have to still **hardcode** region and account id.

Comment: Updated Question by fixing typo issues. I'm looking for a way to not hardcode using `Join` inside `Join` to generate ARN.

Comment: @SNR There is no such way unless you create your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Alternatively, have to use more versitle tools, such as Terraform.

Comment: Understood Thank you.